# Route drawing on google map in android error java.net.UnknownHostException: maps.googleapis.com

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android project where i want to draw a route from my current location to a particular store.The following is my code:

I call the async class GetRouteTask which calls another class.Which is shown below the following code:

```
public void placemarkersonmap()
    {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);


        new GetRouteTask().execute();

    }
 private class GetRouteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

         private ProgressDialog Dialog;
         String response = "";
         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
               Dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
               Dialog.setMessage("Loading route...");
               Dialog.setCancelable(false);
               Dialog.show();
         }

         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
               //Get All Route values
                     document = v2GetRouteDirection.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, GMapV2GetRouteDirection.MODE_DRIVING);
                     if(document!=null){
                      response = "Success";
                     }

                     return response;

         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               googleMap.clear();
               if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
               ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = v2GetRouteDirection.getDirection(document);
               PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(
                           Color.RED);

               for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                     rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
               }
               // Adding route on the map
               googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
               markerOptions.position(toPosition).title(job_object.job_shop_name);
               markerOptions.draggable(true);
               googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
              googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(fromPosition, 12f));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(fromPosition, 12f));

               }

               Dialog.dismiss();
         }
   }
```

The helper class:

```
package com.igloo.classes;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import android.util.Log;

public class GMapV2GetRouteDirection {
   public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
   public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

   public GMapV2GetRouteDirection() { }

   public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
       String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
               + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude 
               + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
               + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

       try {
           HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
           HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
           InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
           DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
           Document doc = builder.parse(in);
           return doc;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
   }

   public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
       NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
       Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
       NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
       Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
       Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
       return node2.getTextContent();
   }

   public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
       NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
       Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
       NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
       Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
       Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
       return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
   }

   public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
       NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
       Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
       NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
       Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
       Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
       return node2.getTextContent();
   }

   public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
       NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
       Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
       NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
       Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
       Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
       return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
   }

   public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
       NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
       Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
       Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
       return node1.getTextContent();
   }

   public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
       NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
       Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
       Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
       return node1.getTextContent();
   }

   public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
       NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
       Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
       Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
       return node1.getTextContent();
   }

   public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
       NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
       ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
       nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
       if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
           for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
               Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
               nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

               Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
               nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
               Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
               double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
               Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
               double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
               listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

               locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
               nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
               latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
               ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
               for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                   listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
               }

               locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
               nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
               latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
               lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
               lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
               lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
               listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
           }
       }

       return listGeopoints;
   }

   private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
       for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
           if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
               return i;
       }
       return -1;
   }

   private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
       ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
       int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
       int lat = 0, lng = 0;
       while (index < len) {
           int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
           do {
               b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
               result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
               shift += 5;
           } while (b >= 0x20);
           int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
           lat += dlat;
           shift = 0;
           result = 0;
           do {
               b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
               result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
               shift += 5;
           } while (b >= 0x20);
           int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
           lng += dlng;

           LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
           poly.add(position);
       }
       return poly;
   }
}
```

I works fine on newer devices.But on older devices(Android 2.6) i get the following exception:

```
11-08 11:14:24.709: W/System.err(4582): java.net.UnknownHostException: maps.googleapis.com
11-08 11:14:24.740: W/System.err(4582):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
11-08 11:14:24.740: W/System.err(4582):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at com.igloo.classes.GMapV2GetRouteDirection.getDocument(GMapV2GetRouteDirection.java:37)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at com.igloo.fragments.RouteFragment$GetRouteTask.doInBackground(RouteFragment.java:282)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at com.igloo.fragments.RouteFragment$GetRouteTask.doInBackground(RouteFragment.java:1)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-08 11:14:24.748: W/System.err(4582):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-08 11:15:33.982: W/System.err(4582): java.net.UnknownHostException: maps.googleapis.com
11-08 11:15:33.990: W/System.err(4582):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
11-08 11:15:33.990: W/System.err(4582):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at com.igloo.classes.GMapV2GetRouteDirection.getDocument(GMapV2GetRouteDirection.java:37)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at com.igloo.fragments.RouteFragment$GetRouteTask.doInBackground(RouteFragment.java:282)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at com.igloo.fragments.RouteFragment$GetRouteTask.doInBackground(RouteFragment.java:1)
11-08 11:15:33.998: W/System.err(4582):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-08 11:15:34.006: W/System.err(4582):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-08 11:15:34.006: W/System.err(4582):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-08 11:15:34.006: W/System.err(4582):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-08 11:15:34.006: W/System.err(4582):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-08 11:15:34.006: W/System.err(4582):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-08 11:15:47.576: W/KeyCharacterMap(4582): No keyboard for id 0
11-08 11:15:47.576: W/KeyCharacterMap(4582): Using default keymap
```

The line of error shown is this line:

```
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
```

which is in the helper class.

The question is why does this code work at certain times but not at other times?
How do i fix the issue?

Comment: have you try to check url in browser ? is it return response or not ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana. The error is not always present.It works fine on newer devices,But sometimes it fails on an older device.I am not saying that it always fails.

Comment: @AchuthanM may be some devices, in which this is not working, may be that devices needs Google Play Service enabled.

Comment: @pratt .It has nothing to do with google play services.The device on which i was getting an issue works fine at certain times but doesnt give the route at other times.